# One to One or Many to One in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm using [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) with mssql.

I try to create One-to-One relation [like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAhuj.png):

So I use the code from sequelize docs:

```
const Player = this.sequelize.define('player', {/* attributes */});
const Team  = this.sequelize.define('team', {/* attributes */});

Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

I got Many-To-One [as you can see in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4SY3.png)

So I have try to do:

```
const Player = sequelize.define('player', { /* attributes */ });
const Team  = sequelize.define('team', { /* attributes */ });

Player.belongsTo(Team);
Team.hasOne(Player);
```

Same result.

How can I do one-to-one relation?

**Edit**

For this code:

```
const Player = sequelize.define('player', { /* attributes */ });
const Team  = sequelize.define('team', { /* attributes */ });

Player.hasOne(Team);
```

This is what `sequelize` does:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[teams]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [teams];
IF OBJECT_ID('[players]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [players];
IF OBJECT_ID('[players]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [players];
IF OBJECT_ID('[players]', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [players] ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) , [createdAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, [updatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([id]));
EXEC sys.sp_helpindex @objname = N'[players]';
IF OBJECT_ID('[teams]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [teams];
IF OBJECT_ID('[teams]', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [teams] ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) , [createdAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, [updatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, [playerId] INTEGER NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([id]), FOREIGN KEY ([playerId]) REFERENCES [players] ([id]) ON DELETE SET NULL);
EXEC sys.sp_helpindex @objname = N'[teams]';
```

And still the problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasOne()` method. not `belongsTo()` that's it :)

Comment: I did `Player.hasOne(Team); Team.hasOne(Player);` but I got an error: `cyclic dependency found. players is dependent of itself.``Dependency chain: players -> teams => players`

Comment: Of course that way you will cause a recursion. you need just Player.hasOne(Team) I strongly suggest you to read the documentation to learn the a,b,c.

Comment: Same. I read it the documentation. but still, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to sequelize [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#hasone) you can use "belongsTo" when information about association is present in the source model and "hasOne" when information about association is present in the target model.

In your case, the information about association is present in the source model (playerId exists on the team model) thus what you should do is:

```
Team.belongsTo(Player)
Player.hasOne(Team)
```

and what you did in the edited answer is correct and should suffice.